# Neo4j update one-to-many relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to update a relationship between two Nodes. The node types are:

1. **Role**
2. **Permission**.

The relationship name is

- **HAS_PERMISSION**.

I would like the query to work for the following two scenarios:

**SCENARIO A.** Add new relationship

When a new permission name is passed by PUT request to the API, the following should occur:

- **STATE**: `admin-[:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->create`
- **PERMISSION PASSED BY REQUEST**: `['create', 'update']` (requestPermissions on Query)
- **NEXT STATE**: `admin-[:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->create` and `admin-[:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->update`

**SCENARIO B**: Delete Relationship

- **STATE**: `admin-[:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->create` and `admin-[:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->update`
- **PERMISSION PASSED BY REQUEST**: `['update']`
- **NEXT STATE**: `admin-[:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->update`

WITH [1] collects all current permissions by converting it to a list. WITH [2] gets the difference between the current permissions and the permissions passed by the request obtaining the permissions that should be deleted and it converts the current permissions into a list of names (its node structure is `{name : 'permission-name'}`. WITH [3] gets the difference between the request permissions and the current permissions obtaining the permissions that should be added. Then the nodes are deleted and added accordingly.

The following query does the work ok. It works as expected on *Scenario A* but on *Scenario B* it does the job but it does not return anything.

```
MATCH (role:Role)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(permissions:Permission) 
WHERE id(role) = 7
SET role = {name: 'admin'}

WITH COLLECT(permissions) AS permissions, 
    ['update'] AS requestPermissions, 
    role

WITH FILTER(permission IN permissions WHERE NOT permission.name IN 
    requestPermissions) AS toDeletePermissions, 
    REDUCE(values = [], permission in permissions | values + 
       permission.name) as permissionsValues,
    requestPermissions,
    role, 
    permissions

WITH FILTER(permission IN requestPermissions WHERE NOT permission IN 
    permissionsValues) AS toAddPermissions, toDeletePermissions, role, 
    permissions

UNWIND (CASE toDeletePermissions WHEN [] THEN [null] ELSE 
    toDeletePermissions END) as permission
    OPTIONAL MATCH (role)-[rel:HAS_PERMISSION]->(permission)
    DELETE rel

WITH toAddPermissions, permissions, role

UNWIND  (CASE toAddPermissions WHEN [] THEN [null] ELSE 
  toAddPermissions END) AS permission
  MATCH (p:Permission {name: permission})   
  MERGE (role)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(p)

WITH role
MATCH (role)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(permissions:Permission)
RETURN role, permissions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may simplify your problem, scenario A and B can be converted to scenario C as "Set role's permissions to this list". Like that, you just need to 'clean' the pre-existing relationships and write new ones.

```
MATCH (role:Role)
WHERE id(role) = 7
SET role = {name: 'admin'}
WITH role, ['update'] as requestPermissions 

// Use optional so that absence of matches doesn't break anything
OPTIONAL MATCH (role)-[rel:HAS_PERMISSION]->(permission:Permission)
WHERE NOT permission.name IN requestPermissions 
DELETE rel

WITH DISTINCT role, requestPermissions
MATCH (permission:Permission)
WHERE permission.name IN requestPermissions
CREATE UNIQUE (role)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(permission)

// Return what we set
RETURN role, permission
```

Much simpler, and less that can go wrong. As for combining DELETE and RETURN in the same query, this can have... weird.. results as the Cypher is one transaction, and the Order the Cypher is done is not guaranteed. So I would recommend only returning the count of deleted items when using DELETE (or at the very least, only return what you have already matched before the DELETE, and deleted items may be empty).

Comment: It is a great way to go but it does not work. I receive an error on CREATE UNIQUE ... WHERE (Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I'). The create unique clause won't create new relationships as is not iterating over the request permission roles.

Comment: @DiegoGallegos Forgot can't Match in CREATE. Just have to break out the match bit. (OPTIONAL so that you don't lose your role if their are none, answer updated)

Comment: Again in the last OPTIONAL MATCH, it cannot add anything new because when testing permission.name IN requestPermissions it is not adding anything from requestPermissions but from existing permission nodes. In addition, on SCENARIO A and on SCENARIO B.

Comment: @DiegoGallegos What do you mean by adding from requestPermissions? The OPTIONAL MATCH is after a WITH, which means that it is matching a new set of permissions with new criteria (but now that I think about it, you should probably be using WITH DISTINCT) And for reference, here is the docs on CREATE UNIQUE (http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/#query-create-unique-relationships) (and I don't understand what "In addition, on SCENARIO A and on SCENARIO B." means)

Comment: When passing 'update' and on db there is 'create' it should delete 'create' and create 'update', it returns this error : 'Expected `permission` to a node, but it is a null'.

Comment: @DiegoGallegos, I updated it so that it will create missing permissions, and only do the  CREATE UNIQUE if permission is not null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144379/discussion-between-diego-gallegos-and-tezra).

Comment: How efficient is iterating over all Permissions and compare it to requestPermissions? This is an OK answer but there should be a more efficient one.

Comment: @DiegoGallegos It depends on how many Permissions there are, and if Permissions.name is a (unique) index. If it is a Unique Index, Cypher should just find them via index scan (and if it doesn't, you can tell it to use the index) Remember that Cypher says what you want, not how to get it. So in general, the more you leave up to Cypher, the more efficient your query will run. (of course, smart DB schema design, and Cypher hints to use that design also help a lot.)